# ajax submission not hitting internal endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I just set up an ajax call to an endpoint the same way I did before when it worked, but I'm getting 500 error:

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def save_file_ajax_endpoint(request):
    print('POST to ajax')
    text = request.POST['text']
    filepath = request.POST['filepath']
    print(filepath)
    print('yo')
    write_content(filepath, text)
    return redirect('index:index')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from index import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',            
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^save/$', views.save_file_ajax_endpoint,  name='save-file'),
)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load html_process %}

{% block body_block %}

    <div id="elephant" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">{{ content }}</div>
    <br>
    <button id="save-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm new-email-button">Save</button>

    <script>
        function determineMode(filepath) {
            var modeString = "ace/mode/" + filepath;
            return modeString;
        }
    </script>

    <script src="/media/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit("elephant");
        editor.getSession().setMode(determineMode('sh'));
        editor.session.setNewLineMode("unix");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.setFontSize(15);
    </script>

    <script>
        $('#save-button').click(function(){
            var textBox = $('#editor').text();
            var filepath = '{{ filepath }}';
            alert(filepath)
            var saveFileEndpoint = {% url 'index:save-file' %};
            $.ajax({
                url: saveFileEndpoint,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    filepath: filepath,
                    text: textBox
                },                
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>



{% endblock %}
```

[image]

I get a 500 on clicking save:

[image]

Why doesn't this button send ajax? Thank you

Comment: 500 error means you have an issue on the server, has nothing to do with the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: If you have `DEBUG=False`, you should be able to see the traceback from within your browser's developer tools.

Comment: It *is* hitting the endpoint; your console shows that the server is returning 500.

Comment: Can you show us the 500 response that you are receiving? I'm assuming from your screen shot you are using Chrome. There's a good extension (arc I think it's called) to do api testing. I suggest you install that it will help you see what's going on and be a good tool for development.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo Advanced Rest Client

Comment: I was not getting server errors for some unknown reason, I wanted help finding where to even read the error. After restarting pc completely, errors showed up in terminal like usual. Weird. Thanks guys